# Scroll and find element in a page using appium on mobile app

Tags: java, android, scroll, gesture, appium

I am writing mobile app automation test for my app.

**Steps**:-

1. List of all articles will displayed - I click on first article
2. In article page, there is a image at center of the article. I want to assert that image is present or image. To do it, I need to scroll and find.

How can i do it?

I have tried the following:-

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
    scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
    js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

**Result**:-

But appium says as Not yet implemented..

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can do one thing Just Scroll to the image by using Text string near that image. Than find that image view element and check whether its enabled or not.

Comment: Content near to that image is not consistent. I have that id of the image. then how can i scroll and find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new TouchAction((MobileDriver)driver).longPress(driver.findElements(By.id("")).get(0)).moveTo(driver.findElements(By.id("")).get(7)).release().perform();
```